# Can someone explain the use of initWithNibName in iOS to me?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have been playing around with UIViewControllers in iOS 6. However there is one thing I don't really understand. When do we use methods like initWithNibName, awakeFromNib and setup? And how do they differ to viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear?

Comment: Have a look at Apple's [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-initWithNibName:bundle:` is the standard initializer for XIB-based UIViewControllers.  It contrasts directly with the rest of Cocoa-Touch (save a few outliers), which are sent `-initWithCoder:` when dearchived.  Note that at this point no setup work has begun.  Sure, super calls through to jump-start NSCoder to "defrost" your XIB, but you have no valid view instance, and should not attempt to set one up in this method.

`-awakeFromNib:` is called immediately after the given class has been "defrosted" and initialized by NSCoder.  At this point, you will still not have a valid view outlet, and so any view-related setup (adding subview, setting properties on the root view, etc.) should be done either in `-loadView` (the only method in which you should ever assign to `self.view`), or `-viewDidLoad`.

`-viewWill/DidAppear` are appearance methods (not necessarily indicators of initialization) which are sent when the associated view is set as root, or when the view above it in a navigation stack is popped off.